# Python module to generate all permutations of possible string replacements in a string?

Tags: python, python-itertools

```
template = "{{ person }} is a {{ quality }} {{ occupation }}"
replacements = {
"person":["John","Matt","Steve"],
"quality":["great","dedicated"],
"occupation":["engineer","student","athelete"]
}

Output:
John is a great engineer
Matt is a great engineer
Steve is a great engineer
John is a dedicated engineer
Matt is a dedicated engineer
Steve is a dedicated engineer
John is a great student
Matt is a great student
Steve is a great student
.............................
```

They can be generated by using lists of lists of replaceable elements and looping over them to generate permutations, and then joining the list elements.

```
list_input =     [["John","Matt","Steve"],["is"],["a"],["great","dedicated"],["engineer","student","athelete"]]

example_permutation = ["John","is","a","great","engineer"]
```

Is there a python module/method which can generate similar permutations ?

Comment: You've even tagged this with `itertools`, which is the module you want. :/

Comment: @Wooble , I wasn't sure if itertools would have the supporting methods,I had only known itertools to generate permutations, but it did not strike my mind that it would be a cartesian product in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just `cartesian product` of the list

```
import itertools

list_input =     [["John","Matt","Steve"],["is"],["a"],["great","dedicated"],["engineer","student","athelete"]]
for element in itertools.product(*list_input):
    print element
```

or you can do directly from your dict @dano(suggested)

```
replacements = {
"person":["John","Matt","Steve"],
"quality":["great","dedicated"],
"occupation":["engineer","student","athelete"]
}

for element in itertools.product(*replacements.values()):
    print("{} is a {} {}".format(*element))


#output 

John is a great engineer
John is a great student
John is a great athelete
John is a dedicated engineer
John is a dedicated student
John is a dedicated athelete
Matt is a great engineer
Matt is a great student
Matt is a great athelete
Matt is a dedicated engineer
Matt is a dedicated student
Matt is a dedicated athelete
Steve is a great engineer
Steve is a great student
Steve is a great athelete
Steve is a dedicated engineer
Steve is a dedicated student
Steve is a dedicated athelete
```

Comment: Why not use `for element in itertools.product(*replacements.values()):`, so the OP can directly apply it to his data structure?

Comment: @dano yes i will add it

Comment: And then the `print` statement would be `print("{} is a {} {}".format(*element))` to get his desired output.